# How can I validate multiple email addresses in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

e.g.: comma seperated in a single textfield: **mail1@domain.com, mail2@someotherdomain, ...**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the TMail::Address module to validate an email as [shown here](http://lindsaar.net/2008/4/14/tip-4-detecting-a-valid-email-address). Custom validations can be added with the `validate` method.

```
validate :check_email_addresses

def check_email_addresses
  email_addresses.split(/,\s*/).each do |email|
    TMail::Address.parse(email)
  end
rescue TMail::SyntaxError
  errors.add(:email_addresses, "are not valid")
end
```

---

**Update:** The TMail::Address module seems to be too lax on what is considered a valid email address (see comments below) so instead you can use a regular expression.

```
validate :check_email_addresses

def check_email_addresses
  email_addresses.split(/,\s*/).each do |email| 
    unless email =~ /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i
      errors.add(:email_addresses, "are invalid due to #{email}")
    end
  end
end
```

There are a variety of regular expression solutions for validating an email address. See [this page for details](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

Comment: does that really work?  
>> ret = TMail::Address.parse "invalid"
=> #<TMail::Address invalid>

Comment: Hmm, I'm guessing in some edge cases that can be a valid email address. But that's not all that helpful for validating emails in a form. I'll update the answer...

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is trying to parse an address list with names in it, as may appear in an email header, the easiest way I found to do that is:

```
header = TMail::HeaderField.new('to', address_list_string)
```

`header.addrs` will then contain an array of `TMail::Address` objects, which you can access for the name, email address, domain, etc.

Comment: I like the readability of using TMail to validate, but I struggled to get this to work on a list. In my case, it seems that TMail insists on comma separated addresses, so I am replacing newlines and semicolons with commas before passing to TMail: `address_list_string.gsub(";",',').gsub("\n",',').gsub("\r",',')` - I added the \r substitution once I had it running on the website.  It's clunky, but it works and it's easy for me to read what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following:

```
module EmailValidator
  self.email_name_regex  = '[\w.%+-]+'.freeze
  self.domain_head_regex = '(?:[A-Z0-9-]+.)+'.freeze
  self.domain_tld_regex  = '(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum)'.freeze
  self.bracketed_email_regex = /\A.<\s(#{email_name_regex}@#{domain_head_regex}#{domain_tld_regex})\s*>.\z/i
  self.unbracketed_email_regex = /\A\s(#{email_name_regex}@#{domain_head_regex}#{domain_tld_regex})\s*\z/i
```

def self.valid_email?(s)
    !(s =~ bracketed_email_regex || s =~unbracketed_email_regex).nil?
  end
end

so then you could do this:

```
address_field.split(/\s*,\s*/).select {|addr| EmailValidator.valid_email?(addr)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at ActiveRecord::Validations::ClassMethods, specifically the validates_each method.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M002161

This will let you pass the attribute as a block and then you can write your own validation method that will split your string and validate each email address to a regular expression.